# Gazelle not creating correct dependencies?

Tags: go, bazel

Consider a repo, `github.com/myacct/sandbox`, with a `ji` directory at the top:

```
$ ls -CFR
.:
BUILD.bazel  WORKSPACE  one/

./one:
oneonone.go

$ cat BUILD.bazel
load("@bazel_gazelle//:def.bzl", "gazelle")

# gazelle:prefix github.com/myacct/sandbox/ji

gazelle(name = "gazelle")
```

Pretty standard stuff, straight out of the docs. I have already run `bazel clean --expunge`. Now:

```
$ bazel run //:gazelle
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed target //:gazelle (66 packages loaded, 7036 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:gazelle up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/gazelle-runner.bash
  bazel-bin/gazelle
INFO: Elapsed time: 23.191s, Critical Path: 5.81s
INFO: 49 processes: 13 internal, 36 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 49 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 49 total actions
```

Let's see what it did:

```
$ cat one/BUILD.bazel
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")

go_library(
    name = "one_lib",
    srcs = ["one.go"],
    importpath = "github.com/symbiont-io/sandbox/ji/one",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    deps = [
        "@org_golang_google_api//calendar/v3:go_default_library",
        "@org_golang_google_api//people/v1:go_default_library",
        "@org_golang_x_net//context:go_default_library",
        "@org_golang_x_oauth2//:go_default_library",
        "@org_golang_x_oauth2//google:go_default_library",
    ],
)

go_binary(
    name = "one",
    embed = [":one_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

The deps look good, that's what I'm importing in `one.go`.

Here is how it fails:

```
$ bazel build //one:one
ERROR: /home/ji/sandbox/ji/one/BUILD.bazel:3:11: no such package '@org_golang_google_api//people/v1': The repository '@org_golang_google_api' could not be resolved and referenced by '//oneonone:oneonone_lib'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//one:one' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.087s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

Comment: The new issue you're running into is definitely something that could use an answer, but I'd break it out into a separate question so that folks with that specific problem can find it more easily in the future.

Comment: Anyway, here's how to fix the new issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/af0f76b6b85b1a8776be82ee58d6a640c73c2111/go/dependencies.rst#proto-dependencies. It actually doesn't have anything to do with Gazelle.

Comment: My bad... I had accidentally removed the prtobuf_deps() from my WORKSPACE file. Adding them back fixed the problem. 

When this covid thing is over, I'll buy you a beer (I'm also in NYC :) )

Comment: Haha, hat would do it. Cheers! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the documentation to actually be very thorough.

Anyway, you need to run [`update-repos`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#update-repos). You can either run a one-off command to import the specific repo you need:

```
bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos google.golang.org/api/people/v1
```

Or you can create a Go module and just import dependencies from `go.mod`:

```
bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod
```

I recommend doing the latter. Create a module with `go mod init` and then you can have a script you run periodically to update your dependencies:

```
# update go.mod
go get -d ./...

# update repos with Gazelle
bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod
```

Comment: I see why you recommended the go mod approach; adding repos one by one as my builds failed was getting tiring. However, this is still a no-go, I updated the original question as there is not enough space in the comment section.